# Count Group By Many-to-Many table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using ASP.NET MVC and have a many-to-many table that as follows:

```
custID | objID
================
  1       2
  1       3
  2       5
  2       2
  3       2
```

Both userID and objID are `Foreign Keys` linking to other tables. What I would like to do is get the highest count based on `objID`. The table above will yield the following results:

```
objID | objName | Price
=======================
  2   | Chicken | 10
```

The `custID` does not matter in this scenario as I just want to get the `objID` with the highest count.

I've tried the following but i'm stuck here:

```
//retrieve many-to-many table
var retrieved = db.Customer.Include(c => c.Objects)
var topID = retrieved.GroupBy(q => q.objID)
                     .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<int> lst = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 2 };
        var count = lst.GroupBy(q => q).OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
                     .First().Key;

  var lstKeyWithCount  lst.GroupBy(i => i).Select(g => new { Key=g.Key,Count=g.Count() });
```

in lstKeyWithCount  variable you get key with count.
in count variable you get most times repeated value.

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick.

```
var topID = retrieved.GroupBy(q => q.objID)
                 .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, Total = g.Count() })
                 .OrderByDescending(g => g.Total).First().Id;
```